# Is it guaranteed that sequence numbers will increment by 1 EventHub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I'm consuming from a single Azure EventHub partition, using the PartitionReceiver class in Java. I'm trying to understand the `x-opt-sequence-number` SystemProperty that is available in each EventData object that I receive.

Is it **guaranteed** that the sequence numbers increment by 1 per EventData consumed and that each possible sequence number exists in the partition? For example if I've consumed an Event with sequence number 5 and another with 10, based on this must there exist events with sequence numbers 6-9?

Thanks!

Comment: Sequence no will save in increment order, I think (not sure) sequence number can be increase across the partition.

Comment: Ahh, do you mean sequence numbers don't repeat in different partitions of the same EH?

Comment: yes (not very sure)

Comment: Sequence numbers are only guaranteed to be unique within the context of a specific partition.  There is no guarantee they are unique or follow any pattern when compared across partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Corrected Context

My understanding was incorrect.  It has been confirmed by the Event Hubs team that sequence numbers are contiguous within the scope of a single partition.

---

#### Original Answer

As I understand it, sequence numbers are not guaranteed to be sequential in the scope of a partition, though they often are.  The only strict guarantee is that they will always be in increasing order with respect to when an event was enqueued to a specific partition.  Sequence numbers are specific to a partition and shouldn't be compared across partitions.

If you need to ensure that you're sequencing with a strict and specific increment, your best bet is likely to be adding a custom bit of metadata for your application domain's sequence number in the user properties collection.  Of course, that does get tricky when coordinating across publishers on multiple machines and like likely to surface performance trade-offs.

Comment: My goal here is to ensure I've consumed every possible event from a partition within a given enqueuedFrom time-window. I thought I could analyse the span of sequence numbers successfully processed and look for gaps (which I've found a lot of). Any ideas on a better way to do this if we can't guarantee sequence number gaps = missed events?

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm following the end-to-end scenario.  Are you saying that you're unsure that you are reading all events or that your processing may not be correctly handling the events that were read?

Comment: "Sequence number incremented by 1" rule is guaranteed on the same partition only. If you send 2 events sequentially and they land on different partitions, 1st event sent may have a greater sequence number than the 2nd event sent.

Comment: I stand corrected.   Serkant is an engineer on the Event Hubs team; his guarantee is the authoritative voice here.

Comment: That does now beg the question as to why you're seeing gaps.   Can you expand on how you're consuming events?