# How can I verify that I've read all possible events from an EventHub partition?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I want to be able to verify within my client that I've processed all possible events from an EventHub partition, but I cannot figure out the best method to do this. I'm using Java `EventHubClient` and `PartitionReceiver` objects.

Initially I thought I could do this by recording the sequence numbers I've seen and comparing to the span of sequence numbers I'd expect (Total messages = max_seq_number - min_seq_number) - but it seems it's not guaranteed the sequence number increments by 1 so this doesn't seem to work ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61121044/is-it-guaranteed-that-sequence-numbers-will-increment-by-1-eventhub?noredirect=1#comment108131898_61121044)).

Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequence number always increments by 1, that is guaranteed per partition.

You can enable receiver runtime metrics in the receiver options and compare current received sequence number to the lastSequenceNumber of subject partition reported in runtime metrics. Comparison will tell how many more events waiting to be received.

See code sample here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/c876a6e0c24a6b02113528e9bcf8d789e9b3c6c9/sdk/eventhubs/microsoft-azure-eventhubs/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/eventhubs/sendrecv/ReceiverRuntimeMetricsTest.java#L76